# How to retain information for the logged in user on page reload or different tabs in browser

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have only started with react and redux and designed the login -sign up page.

Have an action that calls login-sign up API and a corresponding reducer.

I display some of this information on page and use it on some others. Now, I would like this state to be maintained when the browser is reloaded. How do I do it?

I have this header component binding this action that logs the user in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you either store the state in `localStorage`, e.g. by using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) or fetch the initial state from your server.